# Regular expression for name with spaces allowed in between the text and avoid spaces when there is no text

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm trying to write a regular expression for user name in my form.

The regular expression should allow spaces and . when the text is written

Ex : S. Harish Kumar

Check the regEx that I have written so far

```
^[a-zA-Z\s\.]*$
```

The above regEx also accepts any string with just spaces and . which I don't want.  Can you help me with the perfect regEx which doesn't accept spaces and . when no text is entered?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are leading/trailing dots/spaces allowed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just disallow a string that only consists of whitespaces/dots:

```
^(?![\s.]+$)[a-zA-Z\s.]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1D9Myt/1).

The `(?![\s.]+$)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if the whole string contains whitespace or dot chars only.

Comment: Just as a follow-up: [`^\b(?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z.]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z.]+)\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/1D9Myt/3) will make sure no space or dot appear at the start/end and are not used consecutively (but allowing a space-dot/dot-space sequence). However, this is even more restrictive than Dima's approach in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43935344/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `^[a-zA-Z].*[\s\.]*$`

- `^[a-zA-Z]` asserts string starts with a char (a-zA-Z)
- `.*[\s\.]*$` followed by any char dot and spaces included

See following example:

```js
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z].*[\s\.]*$/g;


function check(par){
  console.log(par.value + " match: " + regex.test(par.value));
}
```

```html
Name <input type="text" id="test" value="" onchange="javascript:check(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say a name is a sequence of alphabetic chars delimited by spaces or dots, which can be defined by the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s.]+[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rH5jtc/2